# I have Console app witch runs on server by scheduler and after some count invoking stop working

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

Each time when the application  can't serialize XML from specified URL it tries to send e-mail and write to XML file when the last Email was sent but after some count  of invoking my XML file contains the wrong symbol-">"
P.S- Only this App using this file and we have only one instance of this app at the same time

```
// class constructor
public class XmlEmailService
    {


        private List<EmailSendingForXmlModel> emailList = new List<EmailSendingForXmlModel>();
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<EmailSendingForXmlModel>));
    private bool IsDirty = false;


public XmlEmailService()
        {

            if (File.Exists(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XmlFilePath"]))
            {


                using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XmlFilePath"]))
                    {
                        emailList = (List<EmailSendingForXmlModel>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
                    }


            }
            else
            {
                File.Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XmlFilePath"]).Dispose();
            }
        }



public void Save()
        {

            if (IsDirty)
            {

                using (FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XmlFilePath"]))
                    {
                        serializer.Serialize(stream, this.emailList);
                    }


            }

        }


// Create/Update List of Emails from XML file
public void CreateOrUpdateList(string Email, bool IsSent)
        {

            if (this.emailList.Any(x => x.Email == Email))
            {
                var item = this.emailList.Where(x => x.Email == Email).FirstOrDefault();

                if (item.SendDate <= DateTime.Now.AddMinutes((Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Sending_interval"])) * -1))
                {
                    if (IsSent)
                        item.SendDate = DateTime.Now;                   
                    this.IsDirty = true;

                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (IsSent)
                {
                    this.emailList.Add(new EmailSendingForXmlModel()
                    {
                        Email = Email,
                        SendDate = DateTime.Now
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    this.emailList.Add(new EmailSendingForXmlModel()
                    {
                        Email = Email,
                        SendDate = DateTime.MinValue
                    });
                }
                this.IsDirty = true;
            }

        }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfEmailSendingForXmlModel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">  
  <EmailSendingForXmlModel>
    <Email>TestEmaili@gmail.com </Email>
    <SendDate>2019-10-04T11:36:46.79885+03:00</SendDate>
  </EmailSendingForXmlModel>
</ArrayOfEmailSendingForXmlModel>>
```

Last symbol ">" invoked the error. I don't know where  this symbol  comes from

Comment: Did you check the project Config file?  You are pulling the email list from ConfigurationManager.AppSettings

Comment: The File.Create() call in the constructor got you into trouble.  That allowed you to use File.OpenWrite() to open the file for writing.  Big problem: that file is not likely to be empty.  So when you don't write as much as used to be in the file then you get extra characters, left over from the previous content.  Fix this by using File.Create() in the Save() method so you always start with a clean slate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My hypothesis is that you are not clearing the output file. So what happens is that if the length of the written text (including whitespace characters) is shorter than what is previously contained in file, the "tail" will remain in the file.

From documentation of [File.OpenWrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.openwrite?view=netframework-4.8)

> The OpenWrite method opens a file if one already exists for the file path, or creates a new file if one does not exist. For an existing file, it does not append the new text to the existing text. **Instead, it overwrites the existing characters with the new characters. If you overwrite a longer string (such as "This is a test of the OpenWrite method") with a shorter string (such as "Second run"), the file will contain a mix of the strings ("Second runtest of the OpenWrite method").**

To fix this, make sure you first clear the file before writing to it. The simplest way to do that is to just delete the file if it exists before creating new one to write into.

Answer (score 0):

@Euphoric, you can also use System.IO.StreamWriter that will overwrite the entire file unless specified in the constructor.